# How to find changeset by change in a file in TFS 2010

Tags: tfs

I have a huge css file and want to find a changeset that applied a particular change.
For example in this file

```css
p {
  font-family: Garamond, serif;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 110 %;
  color: red;
  background: white;
}
```

I want to know, when `font-size` was set to `110 %`. But this file is huge and lots of changes commited before and after the required changeset, so I cannot search only for file, I've got too many results.

I also understand that there is quite a problem because this line could move up/down because of some intermediate insertions/deletions.

Could you help me?

Comment: Not sure if this is in TFS but look at http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/11/who-wrote-this-crap.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably looking for Annotate feature in TFS

Look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385979.aspx

> You can annotate a file to learn who made changes and what changes they made in all earlier versions of the file

Comment: That worked perfectly, as annotate panel has a section where parts of file are marked with the latest commits that change them. And by reverting to necessary commit and then applying Annotate again I was able to find the changeset with the change I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the View History feature also, apart from the Annotate feature. However, both will be useless if the person who committed the change, did not put appropriate comment.
If using the View History feature and there are no appropriate comments, you have to go through the list of changesets, right click a changeset->ChangeSet Details->Select your file and Compare with previous version.